Wafer paper for nougat
I would like to make nougats, but it can be a messy affair if their is no wafer paper.
Does anyone have any tips or can anyone give a recipe for making wafer paper for nougat?

Possibly a dupe of https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/94827/how-to-make-wafer-paper but generally, recipe requests are considered off-topic around here.

I would expect buying the paper either from a bigger supermarket or online is much easier than making it yourself. Also you used the tag sugar-free, I know several types of nougat but for all of them sugar is one of the main ingredients?

confectionary paper used for nougat is much thinner than Asian rice paper, and even the Asian rice paper is described as being difficult to make in a uniform thickness. I think you're best off purchasing this ingredient.

Does this answer your question? How to make wafer paper?
